# Is having a 'bad' accept ratio necessarily a bad thing?

Tags: discussion, accept-rate, ratio

I was wondering if having a bad accept ratio was considered a 'bad' thing among users.  Sometimes I feel like I need to accept an answer that may not exactly answer my question just so my accept ratio stays up when it isn't the EXACT answer I was looking for.

Technically I could have have asked 5 total questions and all of which could have "bad" answers that I don't accept which leaves me with a 0%. Although none of my questions were answered correctly, I might still be frowned upon by the community.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The only "bad" thing that can happen is that some users refuse to answer questions of users with low acceptance rate.

If you don't think the right answer has arrived, don't accept. But don't be too picky. If there are answers that solve your problem, just try to accept the best.

Answer (score 8):

83% is not a bad accept rate and doesn't need fixing.  When it drops below ~65, contributors start to wonder why you ask so many unanswerable questions and may skip any that require concentration or research.  They may assume it will be just another unanswerable question and not worth their time.  Below ~35 is bad.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know that I often don't feel like taking the time to write a answer to someone who doesn't fully participate in the discussion, and doesn't do his bit to reward people who bring knowledge into the discussion. So, yeah, it turns some people down.

Answer (score -2):

You can always add your own "answer" and accept it then as far as I understand your accept rate won't do down.

You can say in your answer something like "Sorry, no good answers were posted" but of course wait few days before doing such thing.

Comment: This is an awful idea. You shouldn't post crap as answer. You can, of course, add a well-researched correct answer for your question and accept it though.

Comment: @Mehrdad suppose I asked 3 questions. I don't know the answer and need help on each. Five days pass, and I get answers but nothing that really help or give true solution. You say it's better to leave it be and stay with 0% accept rate? Sorry, but I disagree on this.

Comment: Yes, you'd better stick with 0%.  Note that the accept rate is not displayed if your question count is lower than a limit.  Even then, low accept rate is not inherently wrong.  If you have received **no *reasonable* answer**, don't accept anything, and don't be so obsessed about it.

Comment: I do sometime add my own answer and accept it - but only when I managed to solve the problem, and none of the answers served my purpose.  "Sorry, no good answers were posted" is no answer.